# How to connect my Android application with mongodb.atlas?

Tags: android, mongodb, kotlin, mongodb-atlas

I am new to mongodb. I need to connect my android application with mongodb.atlas. I have already created my cluster and database in mongodb.atlas.

How can I connect my cluster with my android application and make changes in database from application side? What code should I write in java side? Do I need to use mongodb atlas stich for the same?

Comment: This is a bit too broad. One could write lengthy articles about that. StackOverflow works better if you ask more specific questions. Maybe just try and on the way if you encounter problems ask them here.

Comment: @Trilarion I have already tried with much of the stuff which didn't work and also got references which are regarding mLab. I found no proper tutorial regarding databse connection with android application which led me to ask question here.

Answer (score 4):

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.0.3'
}
```

**Java code**

```
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://username:password@www.example.com:12345/db-name" );
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase(uri.getDatabase());
```

Since this is network related, you will need to run all of that in an AsyncTask class.

Following the java tutorials on https://www.mongodb.org/ should be relatively straightforward from here on out.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain the below line as in how the link should be prepared? "mongodb://username:password@www.example.com:12345/db-name"

Comment: You need to pass your server credentials along with url

Comment: ya I got it that in place of username and password , I need to keep my own credentials and db-name should be replaced by my dbname. rest of the url will be same ?

Comment: Which url I need to provide that I am unable to understand. In place of www.example.com:12345 what it should be ? my connection string or any other url ?

Comment: Your connection string along with port number

Comment: port number can be any , or I need to be specific with that? If specific , then how?

Comment: Port number should be your server port number check here https://www.tutorialkart.com/mongodb/mongodb-port/

Comment: dont forget to store the url and credentials into env-like vars or secret properties data when using CI, and take care of the pattern used by atlas for the connection url, also, you can use the driver connection as a dependency when using dagger or hilt :)